# Using Alloy Models

Tags: models, alloy

I'm working on a project about the live upgrade of HA applications in SA 
Forum middleware.
in Part of my research, I need to make a UML profile for my input upgrade campaign file, 
and validate that file regarding some dependency constraints. Now I want to use ALLOY 
instead of UML in my work specially since it's more abstract and formal than UML. (of 
course UML + OCL will be formal.). Now my question is that, if UML + OCL is formal so 
what's the benefit of using the ALLOY?
In general what are the benefits of using Alloy against UML?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there are no tools that let you check your OCL constraints against the UML
model, and generate and visualize valid instances, so if you are planning to do formal analysis of your models + specifications, Alloy might be a better choice.  Even if you're not planning to do much of analysis, Alloy's ability to generate and visualize valid instances is greatly helpful in making sure you got your model and specification right.